# Passing Data From ThirdViewController to FirstViewController Using the Back Button

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, delegates, protocols

I have three view controllers: the `FirstViewController` has two labels, the `SecondViewController` has only a text field and the `ThirdViewController` also has one text field. What I'm trying to do is pass data back from second and third view controllers. I'm able to pass data from second to first, but I'm not able to pass back from third to first. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

FYI, I'm using storyboards.

**FirstViewController**

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, AcceptDataFromSecondVC, AcceptedDataFromThirdVC{

    @IBOutlet weak var dataFromSecond: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dataFromThird: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func acceptDataFromSecond(data: String) {

        dataFromSecond.text = data
    }

    func acceptedDataFromThird(data: String) {

        dataFromThird.text = data
    }
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "SecondSegue" {
        var secondVC = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController
        secondVC.delegate = self
    }

}

}
```

**SecondView controller**

```
protocol AcceptDataFromSecondVC {

    func acceptDataFromSecond (data : String)
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate : AcceptDataFromSecondVC?

    @IBOutlet weak var dataToSend2: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {

        delegate?.acceptDataFromSecond(dataToSend2.text)
    }
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    var thirdVC = segue.destinationViewController as ThirdViewController
    thirdVC.delegate = self.delegate as AcceptedDataFromThirdVC

}

}
```

**ThirdViewController**

```
protocol AcceptedDataFromThirdVC {

    func acceptedDataFromThird (data : String)
}

class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate : AcceptedDataFromThirdVC?

    @IBOutlet weak var dataToSend3: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }
    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {

        self.delegate?.acceptedDataFromThird(dataToSend3.text)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to also set the delegate on your `ThirdViewController` just like you did for the `SecondViewController`.

If it is launched from `FirstViewController`, you could use:

```
var thirdVC = segue.destinationViewController as ThirdViewController
thirdVC.delegate = self
```

If it is launched from `SecondViewController`, you could use:

```
var thirdVC = segue.destinationViewController as ThirdViewController
thirdVC.delegate = self.delegate as AcceptedDataFromThirdVC
```

Make sure `FirstViewController` implements both protocols.

Comment: third VC is launched from the second VC. but I need to pass data back to the first view controller when I press on the back button twice.

Comment: does that mean that the second VC has to implement the protocol for the third VC?

Comment: If you want. Or you could do the second thing that I said which links the `FirstViewController` to the `ThirdViewController`.

Comment: if I do the second it gives an error AcceptDataFromSecondVC is not identical to AcceptDataFromThirdVC

Comment: Cast it, then. You know that it implements both protocols since you know it's a `FirstViewController`; the cast is safe (unless you change the `delegate` to something that doesn't implement both protocols). This whole method isn't really best-practices, so I'm just giving you the answer. It would be better to have a model that you can access freely from all three classes without requiring a specific ordering of events to occur.

Comment: excuse my ignorance but can you please show me how I can cast it

Comment: The same way that you've cast the `segue.destinationViewController`.

Comment: ok I just updated my code above to show you what I did, but its still not working

Comment: You updated the `prepareForSegue` in your `FirstViewController`. You should have added one in `SecondViewController` if that's where you're expecting to launch to `ThirdViewController`.

Comment: ok I just did and now its giving an error "cannot downcast from AcceptedDataFromSecondVC to non-@objc protocol type AcceptedDataFromthirdVC"

Comment: ok so now it works after adding @objc to the protocols thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use Key Value Observing or NSNotifications.

Comment: I'm really still learning this. Can you please explain or give me an example?